# alias giving: ~/.bash_profile: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create an alias for reloading my bash profile.

I added the following line into my `~/.bash_profile`

```
alias src='CMD="source ~/.bash_profile"; echo $CMD;$CMD;'
```

When I try it(I manually run the command first, so now alias `src` is defined), it doesn't work:

```
$ src
source ~/.bash_profile
-bash: ~/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

(Yes, the file is really there) I have similar aliases for other commands they all work. Only this one is causing a problem. Any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there is no file called `~/.bash_profile`, or, specifically, a directory called `~/`. Bash expands `~` into full path (/home/user/, for example). However, it does not expand after substituting the `$CMD` variable.

Try using the full path. Or adding this:

```
FILE="~/.bash_profile" ; eval FILE=$FILE
```

FILE will have now the full substituted path.